# Validation Error using Spring form

Tags: java, spring, validation, jsp, controller

i am trying to persist an Entity using the sf:form.

this is the jsp:

```
<sf:form method="POST" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/addStudent" modelAttribute="student">
<fieldset>
<table>
<tr>
    <th><sf:label path="nb">Number:</sf:label></th>
    <td><sf:input type="text" path="nb"/><br/>
    <sf:errors path="nb"></sf:errors>
</tr>
......
</table>  
</fieldset>
```

the attribute in the entity is like that:

```
@NotNull(message="not null")
@Size(min=5, max=10, message="length min 5")
@Column(name="NB", unique=true)
private String nb;
```

the controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/addStudent", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView addStudent(HttpServletRequest request, @ModelAttribute("student") @Valid Student student, BindingResult bR){

    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("students");
    if(bR.hasErrors()){
        return mav;
    }
    studentService.saveStudent(student);
    return mav;
}
```

Well, when i leave the nb field empty or the entry is to short i get a validation error. my problem is that the error is not shown in the jsp but an exception is thrown:

```
List of constraint violations:[
ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='length min 5', propertyPath=nb, rootBeanClass=class i.have.serious.problem.Student, messageTemplate='length min 5'}  
javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: Validation failed for classes [i.have.serious.problem.Student] during persist time for groups [javax.validation.groups.Default, ]
```

maybe i miss something .. i appreciate any hint or help, thx

**-----------------------------** SOLVED **-----------------------------------**

Answer (score 1):

well indeed .. i missed something -> Support for validating @Controller inputs with @Valid, if a JSR-303 Provider is present on the classpath.

```
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd">

<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

works fine now :) .. thx for caring tho!

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new ModelAndView in the method, this may not be carrying back the bindingResult back to the view.

Can you instead take `ModelAndView` as an additional parameter and see if that works out:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/addStudent", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView neuStudent(HttpServletRequest request, @ModelAttribute("student") @Valid Student student, BindingResult bR, ModelAndView mav){

    mav.setViewName("students");
    if(bR.hasErrors()){
        return mav;
    }
    studentService.saveStudent(student);
    return mav;
}
```

Comment: thx for caring! problem solved as stated beneath:) kudos nevertheless!